# Custom LinearLayout cannot add view after overrided onMeasure or set to match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

> I am not a native English user. Sorry for the bad grammar and spelling.

I have a Dialog that contains a View. The View is inflated by an XML file which contains a CustomView. The CustomView, which inherited from a LinearLayout, add views with `addView()` method.

> - My CustomView: https://gist.github.com/TomazWang/e1ddcc32fb2f733d874022ee9c4cffdd
> - Codes that generate the dialog: https://gist.github.com/TomazWang/61d9ad5df3c24bfaa06a78d8a1bcab13

The problems were:

1. When the layout_height of CustomView is set to `match_parent`, the child views in CustomView won't show.
2. After the layout_height of CustomView is set to `wrap_content`, the child views were shown, but the `onMeasure()` method takes too long.
3. I override the `onMeasure()` method. The method was not slowing my app. However, the child views are gone again.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @VishvaDave I post my code with Gist. Is there any way to embed gist in stackoverflow question post?

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it, but there seem to be a number of mistakes in your `onMeasure()` method. The first one is about missing parantheses.

```
int desiredHeight = mChildHeight * mEditors.size() - 1
            + (mViewOther == null ? 0 : mViewOther.getHeight())
            + (mViewTitle == null ? 0 : mViewTitle.getHeight());
```

should probably read

```
int desiredHeight = mChildHeight * (mEditors.size() - 1)
            + (mViewOther == null ? 0 : mViewOther.getHeight())
            + (mViewTitle == null ? 0 : mViewTitle.getHeight());
```

The second mistake is about your call to **`setMeasuredDimension()`**. It is **not necessary** since this is what the call to `super.onMeasure(...)` does. Go check the source.

The third mistake is about when to call `super.onMeasure(...)`. You want to change how the superclass measures, so do not **call `super.onMeasure(...)`** at the beginning, but **at the end of your custom `onMeasure`**.

The fourth mistake is connected to the third; it is about the parameters you use when calling `super.onMeasure(...)`. Do not use the regular `LinearLayout` parameters, but your computed values. In order to **make a new `MeasureSpec` from your height variable**, do:

```
int newHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, heightMode);
```

And then **call `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeightMeasureSpec);`**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that problem is that default orientation of LinearLayout is horizontal ([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation)), so if the first child's width of your custom view fits parent's width (match_parent) you will see only one item - first.

Try to modify `init()` method of your custom view with following changes:

```
private void init() {
    this.mEditors = new HashMap<>();
    mEditors.put("Other", new DataVO("other"));
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
}
```

I hope it will help.